# how to trigger focus event on a textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, focus, eventtrigger

How to trigger focus event on a textbox using javascript?

For example in jQuery we can trigger the focus event with `$('#textBox').focus()`.

Likewise do we have any similar trigger functionality in pure javascript?

Comment: Live the onfocus event, perhaps, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp?

Answer (score 20):

I had to fiddle with this finally, and came up with something that seems to work cross browser:

```
function triggerFocus(element) {
    let eventType = "onfocusin" in element ? "focusin" : "focus";
    let bubbles = "onfocusin" in element;
    let event;

    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        event = document.createEvent("Event");
        event.initEvent(eventType, bubbles, true);
    }
    else if ("Event" in window) {
        event = new Event(eventType, { bubbles: bubbles, cancelable: true });
    }

    element.focus();
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

It takes into account that some browsers support `focusin` events, and some only support `focus` events. It sets focus using the native `focus` function, and then dispatches a "focusin" event or "focus" event, depending on which the browser supports.

Tested in:

- Firefox 62
- Chrome 69
- Internet Explorer 11 (yeah, yeah. I know. We have to support it at work, though)
- Microsoft Edge 15

And to use it:

```
let foo = document.getElementById("foo");

triggerFocus(foo);
```

This is universal and should work with any element that can receive focus.

---

**Update #1**

The jQuery `focus()` function will not trigger native focus handlers. I hit a bit of snag when mixing native focus handlers attached via `HTMLElement.addEventListener(...)` and focus event handlers attached via jQuery. While `jQuery.focus()` will trigger handlers attached using `addEventListener()`, the `dispatchEvent()` function *will not* trigger event handlers attached via `$("...").focus(event => { ... })`. Just bear that in mind if you use this solution.

Comment: "root is not defined"

What is root??

Comment: @beliha: sorry about that. I had a typo in the code, which I corrected. It should be `element` instead.

Comment: Fantastic. This should be the accepted answer, it's the only that works!

Comment: Hey, actually, I feel this answer is good one, but I got this error 'Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function' on firefox 102 version. maybe, what is my mistake?

Comment: @jis0324: The `element` variable needs to be an instance of HTMLElement (or one of its sub-classes). Basically you can only trigger an event on an HTML tag. If `element.nodeName` is `undefined` you do not have an element that supports events.

Comment: alright, the element was the jquery selector, it was list. I just tried with element[0], and it works. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple: `Element.focus()`

***This will not trigger the onfocus event*** See Greg's answer if that is a requirement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

http://jsfiddle.net/eekn6nb9/

Comment: @Fahmi my thought as well!

Comment: I think I know why: `Element.focus()` doesn't trigger `onfocus` events, at least in my testing. the `dispatchEvent` method suggested by Greg does.